# Getting rid of duplicate entries in SQL Query with aggregate function and

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I have two tables, tblMembers and tblBills.
They look something like this, just with more columns and rows in the original:

tblMembers:

| ID | MemberStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Active' |
| 2 | 'Active' |
| 3 | 'Active' |
| 4 | 'Inactive' |
| 5 | 'Active' |

tblBills:

| ID | Year | Payd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2019' | "Checked" |
| 1 | '2020' | "Checked" |
| 1 | '2021' | "Checked" |
| 1 | '2022' | "Checked" |
| 2 | '2017' | "Checked" |
| 2 | '2018' | "Checked" |
| 2 | '2019' | "Unchecked" |
| 3 | '2017' | "Unchecked" |
| 3 | '2018' | "Unchecked" |
| 3 | '2019' | "Unchecked" |
| 4 | '2017' | "Checked" |

I know want to select from those two tables the entries of "Active" members, where the members last payd their bill. If they never payd a bill, I want to select the entry when they last got a bill but didn't pay it (aka Payd is "Unchecked").

The Payd column is a column with ticks that are checked or uncheced.

I have this:

```
SELECT tblMembers.ID, Bills.lastBill, Bills.Payd, tblMembers.MemberStatus
FROM tblMembers LEFT JOIN (select ID, Payd, max(Year) as lastBill from tblBills group by ID, Payd)  AS Bills ON tblMembers.ID= Bills.ID
WHERE tblMembers.MemberStatus='Active'
```

Which gives me:

| ID | LastBill | Payd | MemberStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2022' | "Checked" | 'Active' |
| 2 | '2018' | "Checked" | 'Active' |
| 2 | '2019' | "Unchecked" | 'Active' |
| 3 | '2019' | "Unchecked" | 'Active' |
| 5 |  | "Unchecked" | 'Active' |

Member with ID 1 always payd their bills, so their is only one entry in the end result.
Member with ID 2 last payd in 2018 but got a bill in 2019 which he didn't pay.
Member with ID 3 last got a bill in 2019 but didn't pay.
Member with ID 4 is not shown in the end result, since it's status is "Inactive".
Member with ID 5 never got a bill, never payd a bill and is active (e.g. a recently added, new member).

Now this result looks almost like I want it, except for this entry:

| ID | LastBill | Payd | MemberStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | '2019' | "Unchecked" | 'Active' |

This is a duplicate which happens (I think) because the aggregate function GROUP BY ID, Payd also groups by Payd. But I have to include Payd into the GROUP BY, since I get an error otherwise.
I don't want this duplicate, since this Member has already payed once and
I only want

1. the last time that they payd
2. the last time they got a bill if they never payd
3. The entry with LastBill empty and Payd "Unchecked" if they never got a bill.

I found a workaround by sorting by ID and Payd, exporting to excel, importing into pandas and then  getting rid of the duplicates (df.drop_duplicates('ID')) but I'd like to have all this in a nice and simple SQL query...

Thanks for your help!

---

As further resources for the functions used by @Spencer Barnes I found this:

Dmin and Dmax:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dmin-dmax-functions-f5c6de87-8752-4f29-ab4b-c554053d299f

Nz function:
[https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php#:~:text=The%20Microsoft%20Access%20Nz%20function%20lets%20you%20return,will%20return%20a%20zero%20or%20a%20zero-length%20string](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php#:%7E:text=The%20Microsoft%20Access%20Nz%20function%20lets%20you%20return,will%20return%20a%20zero%20or%20a%20zero-length%20string).

Iif function:
https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas to calculate:

- tblMembers.ID
- For that member, if they payed, last paid date, else most recent bill, else null
- Whether they've ever payed, as 'Checked' or 'Unchecked' or Null if they've never had a bill
- Member status

These calculations can be done separately using domain aggregate functions, without the need for a subquery.

```
SELECT 
    tblMembers.ID, 
    Nz(DMax("Year", "tblBills", "Payd AND ID=" & tblMembers.ID), DMax("Year", "tblBills", "ID=" & tblMembers.ID)) AS LastBill, 
    Dmin("Payd", tblBills, "ID=" & tblMembers.ID) AS Payd,
    tblMembers.MemberStatus
FROM tblMembers
WHERE tblMembers.MemberStatus='Active'
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I tried to implement this but I get a Syntax error.

Microsoft Access:
Syntaxfehler (fehlender Operator) in Abfrageausdruck ...

My query is actually in german:
SELECT 
    tblMitglieder.MitgliledID, 
    Nz(DMax("Jahr", "tblRechnungen", "Bezahlt AND ID=" & tblMitglieder.MitgliedID), DMax("Jahr", "tblRechnungen", "ID=" & tblMitglieder.MitgliedID) AS LetzteRechnung,
    Dmin("Bezahlt", tblRechnungen, "ID=" & tblMitglieder.MitgliedID) AS Bezahlt,
    tblMitglieder.MitgliedStatus
FROM tblMitglieder
WHERE tblMitglieder.MitgliedStatus='Mitglied'

Comment: I expect the issue is with the 'Payd' (Bezahlt) criteria in `"Bezahlt AND ID="` - perhaps try `"Bezahlt = 1 AND ID ="`?

Comment: Is this the same as meaning "Bezahlt == True and ID ="? Is there not a closing bracket miaaing too? I count 4 opening brackets ans 3 closing ones.

Comment: You're right, I missed a closing bracket before `AS LastBill,` - edited the answer to include that, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes! At last it worked. I sabotaged myself a bit, since I translated and simplified the table names into english for Stack Overflow and had to hunt down some bugs because of that. after translating back.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it worked for you! Please accept the answer so the question shows as answered to other StackOverflow users.

Comment: What is strange is that the "Bezahlt" / "Payd" column has now the value -1 when it is True,  0 when they got a bill but never payed and empty when they never got a bill and never payd. Is there a way to rename the return values, so that it would be "Yes" or "True" instead of -1, "No" or "False" instead of 0 and maybe even "NA" for the third case? How does this part work - "Payd AND ID=" & tblMembers.ID - I don't how you can put "Payd AND ID=" into quotation marks and it still works. And why did you write AND in one place and a & in another? @Spencer Barnes

Comment: The quotation marks are there because the Domain functions (in this case Dmax) take strings as their arguments, however those strings have to be valid SQL code (for the criteria parameter at least). SQL uses `AND` to join multiple criteria, and vba uses `&` to join multiple text strings. That's how both got used within the same function.

Comment: To change the output of the "Payd" column, change that line in the SELECT clause from `Dmin("Payd", tblBills, "ID=" & tblMembers.ID) AS Payd` to `Nz(Iif(Dmin("Payd", tblBills, "ID=" & tblMembers.ID), "Yes", "No"), "N/A") AS Payd`

Comment: Thanks a lot. for the additional explanations! I didn't realize that you could combine SQL and Visual Basic (that's what vba means I assume) in such a way.

This works almost perfectly. It just seems as if no values evalute to "N/A" in my statements.
This is not a big problem, since if they never got a bill, the statement "No" works just as fine as "N/A" for my purposes.
Cheers :D

Comment: Yes, VBA stands for Visual Basic for Applications. I didn't actually test that solution, but if you added it as an extra column so you can compare the old and new solution side-by-side you can see if it's evaluating correctly. If not, look into `Iif` and `Nz` functions separately and see if you can work out a fix yourself